# UWP ObservableCollection<string> does not bind to TextBox

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml, observablecollection

In XAML, I have an `ItemsControl` binded to an `ObservableCollection<string>`.
Inside it as `ItemControl.ItemTemplate`, a TextBox binded to the string.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyNames, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyNames = new ObservableCollection<string> {"aa", "bb", "cc" };
```

If I edit any text box I receive the **Error**:

```
Error      
Cannot save value from target back to source. Binding: Path='' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String>';
target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox' (Name='null');
target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

How do I link the text box to the string value? While respecting MVVM pattern of course. `x:Bind` I don't know if it can bind to the default value given by `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `string` is immutable and cannot be modified.

If you want to just *display* the values from the `ObservableCollection<string>` in the `TextBoxes`, you could use a `OneWay` binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

If you want to be able to *edit* the values, you need to replace the `ObservableCollection<string>` with an `ObservableCollection<YourType>` where `YourType` is a custom type which has a `string` property that can be set to a new value:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomType> MyNames = 
        new ObservableCollection<CustomType> 
        { 
            new CustomType { Value ="aa" },
            new CustomType { Value ="bb" },
            new CustomType { Value ="cc" }
        };
}

public class CustomType
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Content="{Binding}" using x:Bind? I mean binding to default value.